# vb.net if database not found open a OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I use following code to set a connection to my database: `Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb")`
I wanted to extent this function by checking if the database exists and If NOT to open a `FileOpenDialog` to choose another database in another folder. I cant seem to get it to work because when I place the `FileOpenDialog` on my Main form it throws an Exception error.

```
Public Function Jokendb() As OleDbConnection
Dim FileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb"
            If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
                Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb")
            Else
                'Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
                Dim str As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
                'If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    
                ' Get the file name.
                Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Try
                    ' Read in text.
                    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
                    Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & text)
                Catch ex As Exception
    
                    ' Report an error.
                    Me.Text = "Error"
                End Try
                'End If
            End If
    End Function
```

Comment: what does the Exception error says?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException

Comment: why did you comented this line?       'Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() this is where the OpenFileDialog1 shows up and lets you select the other file, if you uncoment that it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why those line are comented but i think your code could work with these changes:

```
    Public Function Jokendb() As OleDbConnection
Dim FileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb"
            If IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
                Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb")
            Else
               OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
                'Dim str As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
                'If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    
                ' Get the file name.

                 Dim path As String = ""
                    If OpenFileDialog1.filename <> "" Then
                        path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                    End If
                Try
                    ' Read in text.
                    Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
                    Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & text)
                Catch ex As Exception
    
                    ' Report an error.
                    Me.Text = "Error"
                End Try
                'End If
            End If
    End Function
```